# Is there such a word as repercussionless

Tags: is-it-a-word

Is there such a word as repercussionless. Or what word would mean something like that??

Comment: It's a regularly-formed word, whose meaning is clear. Yes it's a word. (It might be a nonce-word)  Whether any dictionaries have recorded it or not is irrelevant.

Comment: The concept might be more commonly expressed as "repercussion-free".

Comment: What's really fun is inflecting words with combined suffixes -less and -ness. Repercussionlessness (impunity)

Answer (score 3):

The suffix [*-less*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-less), ‘devoid of, not having,  not susceptible to’ is as old as the language itself and can still form new adjectives from virtually any noun. Printed dictionaries rarely give such derived words their own entries but may include them in a list at the end of the entry for the root noun.

While the suffix is still productive, there are difficult to define restraints of acceptability. For instance, most readers would not find a noun phrase such as *cabinetless kitchen design* unusual, but something like *an [honestyless](https://books.google.de/books?id=wIaGLUFHtxsC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=%22honestyless%22&source=bl&ots=leDOZDSJt5&sig=ACfU3U2SQ15ur1siVjGFYEg7Ru3SSyB9XA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi6maSJzKTgAhWG2OAKHVlwAWgQ6AEwDnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22honestyless%22&f=false) politician* would raise eyebrows. Most speakers would likely prefer saying *a dishonest politician* or one *without honesty*.

A [Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with+no+repercussions%2Cwith+no+repercussion%2Cwithout+repercussion%2Cwithout+repercussions&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwith%20no%20repercussions%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20no%20repercussion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwithout%20repercussion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwithout%20repercussions%3B%2Cc0) shows that *with no repercussions* or *without repercussion(s)* are far more frequently used than *repercussionless*, which doesn’t even register in a Google Books query. This means that in a vast corpus of 189 billion words, it occurs less than 40 times.

[image]

This does not mean that no one has ever formed the word before:

> [*Repercussionless*](https://books.google.de/books?id=OyMrAQAAIAAJ&q=%22repercussionless%22&dq=%22repercussionless%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjzwZSiyKTgAhVDLewKHYSLD2c4ChDoATABegQIARAJ) decisions are few and far between.  — David Richard Willings, *How to use the case study in training for decision making*, 1968, 47.
>
> …to enjoy a more childish fantasy of repercussionless dependence, pretence, desire, ... — George William Mallory Harrison, Z. Philip Ambrose *Satyr Drama: Tragedy at Play*, 2005, 176.
>
> You’d think they would have wanted this place, a site of unchecked and almost repercussionless speed. But the military didn’t want an enormous salt desert. — Rachel Kushner, *The Flamethrowers*, 2013, 20.

Each writer must decide whether *repercussionless* sounds more like a *cabinetless kitchen* or an *honestyless politician*. In the first example, I would prefer *decisions with no repercussions*, but I find the other two rather elegant. It’s up to you to decide.